# Paypal mobile express checkout with java

Tags: paypal

I have developed a mobile application which required to integrate with paypal, my back end server is RESTfull java server. So in order to integrate with paypal, i obtain "deviceReferenceTokenWithAppId" from client end calls a servlet at back end server along with other details (cartId..etc), When the request comes to servlet i do some back end operations and calls paypal to get the specific "SetExpressCheckout" token required for mobile payment.

```
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData.append(USER).append("=").append(Constants.PAYPAL_MERCHANT_USER);
        postData.append("&").append(PASSWORD).append("=").append(Constants.PAYPAL_MERCHANT_PASSWORD);
        postData.append("&").append(SIGNATURE).append("=").append(Constants.PAYPAL_MERCHANT_SIGNATURE);
        postData.append("&").append(METHOD).append("=").append("SetExpressCheckout");
        postData.append("&").append(VERSION).append("=").append("88");
        postData.append("&").append(AMOUNT).append("=").append(amount.toString());
        postData.append("&").append(CANCEL_URL).append("=").append(Constants.PAYPAL_MERCHANT_CANCEL_URL);
        postData.append("&").append(RETURN_URL).append("=").append(Constants.PAYPAL_MERCHANT_RETURN_URL);
        byte[] postDataArr = postData.toString().getBytes(UTF-8);
        // Hit the the URL.

        URL url = new URL("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp");
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new CustomizedHostnameVerifier());
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataArr.length));


        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream());
        output.write( postDataArr );
        output.flush();
        output.close ();

        rc = conn.getResponseCode();
```

My problem is if i call the paypal nvp, i dont get a valid token as the response, instead i get following error,

```
Key - TIMESTAMP - value : 2012-06-11T18:16:02Z
 Key - CORRELATIONID - value : 207108cab758a
 Key - ACK - value : Failure
 Key - VERSION - value : 88
 Key - BUILD - value : 2975009
 Key - L_ERRORCODE0 - value : 10002
 Key - L_SHORTMESSAGE0 - value : Security error
 Key - L_LONGMESSAGE0 - value : Security header is not valid
 Key - L_SEVERITYCODE0 - value : Error
```

Can somebody tell me why do i get this error? have i missed anything here?

If i can successfully get the TOKEN, next i have to redirect my servlet response to  following Url to get mobile checkout view to mobile application.

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout-mobile&drt="+<deviceReferenceTokenWithAppId>+"&token="+<TOKEN from payal nvp>
```

Appreciate if someone can guide me to a correct path if i have done a mistake here..

Answer (score 0):

It means your API credentials are incorrect for the endpoint you're accessing.
Try replacing "PASSWORD" by "PWD"; authentication is done with a 'USER', 'PWD' and 'SIGNATURE' with PayPal.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I found the error, i have entered paypal merchant account number instead the user id. However i still have the problem which is it doesnt show the amount to be charged in paypal view, I tried  setting both 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' with VERSION 88.0 and 'AMT' with VERSION 62.0 with the amount (2 decimal digit value). but it doesnt show the required amount to be paid for the user in paypal window.

Comment: That's a separate issue which you didn't mention initially. Either way, to fix that; append "useraction=commit" to your PayPal redirect URL (so it reads https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-xxxxxx&useraction=commit)